How to delete the start screen from the Cordova application
I want to delete the start screen that appears in the application used in Cordova
I tried more than one solution but it didn't work
I searched for drawable files located in the res path
But I couldn't find the files
Use the latest version of Cordova
12.0.0 (cordova-lib@12.0.1)

You can't delete the SplashScreen. You need to override with your own images and settings.

How do I change it and is there a way to reduce the time it appears?

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/12.x/core/features/splashscreen/index.html
